# How can IntelliJ refactor class constants to an external class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have a series of 30 or so private class constants declared and used in Fragment.java. I want to refactor the declarations into public declarations in Constants.java such that all occurrences of `VARIABLE_NAME` in Fragment.java are replaced with `Constants.VARIABLE_NAME`

Tips appreciated on how to use this. I am using Android Studio built on top of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the menu "Refactor", and choose "Move...". Then select the constants you want to move and enter the class where you want to move them.

Comment: Piece of cake! Thanks :D